# Dataprep pivot transform

Tags: pivot, google-cloud-dataprep

I'm new to Dataprep and now trying to create a pivot table using the "Pivot Transform" 
https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Pivot-Transform_57344645#example---basic-pivot

I searched the documents and the syntax looks simple enough, except for the fact that it is out of context and not sure where to use it.
syntax is : 
`pivot col: (the parameter to be used as col) value: (value to present)  group: (what to group by)`

Other solutions that I found here and elsewhere all require lots of code and heavily rely on knowing the columns in advance 
e.g : using `case when ____ = 'name of col'`  to pivot the data

any idea will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you have already imported the dataset with the data and then you created a new flow. When you add the dataset to the flow you can then add a recipe. You can find details on how to do so in the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-dataprep).

Regarding, the pivot transform, once you have added the recipe click on the `Recipe` button on top and then select `Add New Step` as depicted here:

[image]

Then, in the `Transformation` text box you can start typing `pivot` and select the Pivot transform as seen below. A menu will appear and you can apply the parameters using the UI.

[image]

Otherwise, you can just copy and paste the formula in the text box. For example:

```
pivot col:Date value:SUM(Sales) group:State
```

And the fields will be filled in and you can check the preview of the pivot transform:

[image]